# Couldn't display &(ampersand) in message body in gmail while sending mail

Tags: ios, objective-c, character-encoding, special-characters, openurl

I working on mail sending feature in my app. Here in message body of Gmail app while sending mail from my app. It is not displaying `&` and `'` which are special characters.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
    //Suject 
    NSString *strSubject = @"Subjet";
    // Message Body
    __block NSMutableString *messageBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    // gmmmailto
    //googlegmail:///co?subject=<subject text>&body=<body text>
    NSURL *checkGmailAppURL  = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"googlegmail:///co?to=&subject=hi&body=hi" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:checkGmailAppURL])
    {
        [messageBody appendFormat:@"%@\n\n", @"Hi I want sell this application & want be free"];
        NSString *urlFinal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"googlegmail:///co?subject=%@&body=%@", strSubject, messageBody];
        NSURL *emailUrlFinal = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlFinal stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:emailUrlFinal];
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting body with `isHTML:NO` parameter?

Comment: @alexburtnik I am sending mail using             [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:emailUrlFinal];
and here I am not able to find such option.

Comment: Edit your question with full code sample of how you're doing this. What exactly is `emailUrlFinal`?

Comment: Hey @alexburtnik, I had added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method to replace special character from your string.

Pass your string with special characters to below method:

```
-(NSString*)replaceSpecialCharsFromString:(NSString*)str
{
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"&#39;"];

    return str;
}
```

Now, use `str` in mail message body and check if it solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `MFMailComposeViewController`, which was designed for sending emails from apps. Here is a code example of how you can use it:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MFMailComposeViewController.h>

@interface ViewController () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self sendEmail];
}

- (void) sendEmail {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController* mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
        mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailController setSubject:NSLocalizedString(@"Feedback", @"")];
        [mailController setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Feedback", @"")];
        [mailController setToRecipients:@[@"example@gmail.com"]];
        [mailController setMessageBody:@"Hello & ampersand" isHTML:NO];
        if (mailController) {
            [self presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
    else {
        //show UIAlertView
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {
    //Handle completion
}

@end
```

There wouldn't be any issues with `&` or `'`

**Edit:**

If you still want to use gmail app try the code below, it worked for me:

```
NSString *messageBodyRaw = @"Hi I want sell this application & want be free\n\n";
NSString *messageBody = [messageBodyRaw urlEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *urlFinal = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"googlegmail:///co?subject=%@&body=%@", strSubject, messageBody];
NSURL *emailUrlFinal = [NSURL URLWithString:urlFinal];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:emailUrlFinal];
```

NSString+URLEncoding.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface NSString (URLEncoding)
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
@end
```

NSString+URLEncoding.m:

```
#import "NSString+URLEncoding.h"

@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)    
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                 (CFStringRef)self,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                                                 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding)));
}    
@end
```

Comment: Its working fine in default mail sending functionality.

Comment: If it was working fine, you wouldn't ask a question about not working `&`, right? The thing is that the approach you're using is not "default" as you said and moreover it will fail if there is no google mail app on a device, while the default approach which I posted will work.

Comment: My question contains "in message body of gmail app" which clarify that it's not working for gmail app. I have installed gmail and its opening but the encoding also not working for & and '. And adding %26 and %E2%80%99 simultaneously.

Comment: Couldn't find the method 'urlEncodeUsingEncoding' which encode string and returns string as well.

Comment: @MehulChuahan My bad, sorry. Include the required method in NSString category. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126713/discussion-between-mehul-chuahan-and-alexburtnik).

Comment: If any user don't use native mail app you cant send mail.

Comment: @ArielAntonioFundora You're right, and in that case `canSendMail` check will fail and you just need to handle that case. Anyway this is `a standard interface for managing, editing, and sending an email message` according to documentation.